# Jenkins plugin - Merge build queue?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm looking for the jenkins plugins.

Here is my scenario;

1) Job B's quiet period is set to 10 minutes.

2) Job B will have 10 queued builds.

3) After 10 minutes, job B-1 starts running.

4) After B-1 finished, then B-2 starts running.

5) ...

==> Instead of running a single B-1 build in step 3), I want to gather all the 10 queued build's parameters and run a merged build B-x, and discard all the 10 build queues.

Is it possible??

Comment: Editted question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if I got your question you have a parameter job with 10 jobs in queue , and you want to run only the last one ?

If yes you should use some groovy script to check the queue before you trigger the job or inside the job as build step, and clean all previous jobs that exist in the queue.

here is an example to clean jobs for a specific branch , you can modify it for your needs. let me know if you need any help

Thanks , Mor

```
import jenkins.model.*

def branchName = build.environment.get("GIT_BRANCH_NAME")
def buildNo = build.environment.get("BUILD_NUMBER")

println "checking if need to clean the queue for" + branchName + "  build      number : " + buildNo

def q = Jenkins.instance.queue
q.items.each { 
    println("${it.task.name}:")
}

q.items.findAll { it.task.name.startsWith(branchName) }.each {
  q.cancel(it.task) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You sound to be describing a [matrix project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin) which enables a matrix of different build parameter combinations.

If you had 3 different parameters with three different options, this would give you 9 builds, each in its own workspace. There are options to remove some combinations

This is a [good explanation of matrix builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project)

Comment: I checked Matrix project plugin but it's not what I wanted. I just edit my query clearly...